# How to change the attribute display name when returning it as json in mvc?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, localization

I have a class

```
public class ProjectResultClass
{
    public double F7 { set; get; }
}
```

in the controlller i fill it with data and want send it to page

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CalculateProject(int Project)
{
     ProjectResultClass Response= new ProjectResultClass(); 
     Response.F7 = 123.4;
     return Json(Response);
}
```

in the page a get  `F7: 123.4`

I want to give the attribute another name for display.
better use it's to bring the name from resources file
something like

```
public class ProjectResultClass
{
     [DisplayName = "MycustomResourceKey"]
     public double F7 { set; get; }
 }
```

Comment: You can just pass back an anonymous object and use whatever names you want (and read the name from the resource file)

Comment: How can i use resources in an anonymus object?

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
ProjectResultClass Response = new ProjectResultClass();
Response.F7 = 123.4;
return Json(new { MycustomResourceKey = Response.F7 });
```